# How to use Javascript to reload requested page from custom 505 error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http-status-code-505

I've created a **custom 505 error page** for my site (as the default one that shows up is pretty nasty on the eyes). Everything is as it should be but I'm unsure about my usage of JS, I am trying to link the '**Retry**' button in this image:

[image: Image 001]

to a javascript/jQuery action that will reload the page that was initially requested.

i.e If the user requested **example.com/thispage** and they were shown the custom '500 Internal Server Error' page, when they click on 'Retry' the reload request would be for the **example.com/thispage** page.

The javascript I'm using is:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href"><img src="IMAGE SOURCE HERE"></a>
```

In test mode (i.e loaded from my local documents folder) this just refreshes the custom error page.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

**1) Will this reload the requested URL or the custom 505 error file;**

**2) If it will reload the file how can I use JS to reload the initial page request?**

*Note: I have included jQuery:*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the head of the document.

Comment: Firstly, use `window.location.reload()` to reload the page on button click. To answer #1, it will load whatever the current URL is, so exactly what gets reloaded will depend on how you redirect to the 505 error page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, thanks! Without wanting to sound like an amateur I'm using Wordpress as the site's CMS, I'm not sure what the default behaviour is here, all the posts I've read are about fixing these errors instead of trying to spoof one so that I can test how things load :/ do you know what the correct method would be for this setup?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how Wordpress does this internally, but you need to ensure that you do a 307 redirect to the error page so that the original URL is retained so that any requests to reload the page attempt to access the original resource, not the error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay that's great, thank you for clarifying this for me I'll see if I can work it out and post back a full working solution. :) I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
window.location.href=document.referrer
```

but i'm ot sure it will work in every situation

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the problem in the question

Comment: sorry,i tought that the server error triggered a redirect to the Internal server error page